# Динамический и статический IP одновременно на одном интерфейсе

Tags: linux, сеть, dhcp

Стоит задача обеспечить получение динамического IP при статическом (статических) IP, используя Network Manager.
Решил задачу наполовину, создав новое подключение командой:

```
nmcli connection add con-name "default_con" ifname eth0 autoconnect yes type ethernet
```

и добавив нужный адрес так:

```
nmcli con mod "default_con" ipv4.addresses "192.168.1.10"
```

И это работает, пингуется как обычный второй статический адрес - но только тогда, когда машина успешно получает IP по DHCP. А до этого момента - никакого адреса нет вообще.
Будьте добры подскажите, как быть.

Comment: На интерфейс можно навесить алиасы.

Comment: @0andriy Вы имеете в виду через /etc/network/interfaces? Каким образом это будет взаимодействовать с NetworkManager'ом? Поподробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1259634 Может сами погуглите? Я-то не в курсе деталей вашей задачи,

Comment: @0andriy эти костыли 2009ого года немного устарели

Comment: маски не хватает

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в Вашей настройке в том что не установили маску к данному адресу - комп не знает куда слать ARP и как маршрутизировать локальную подсеть.

У меня на компе (не знаю с какой версии доступно одновременно авто и статический ип)

- nm-connection-editor 1.8.22
- networkmanager 1.20.2

Так вот в графическом интерфейсе есть нужные вам параметры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
3: wlp0s16f0u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:48:7a:91:c4:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.117.107/24 brd 192.168.117.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s16f0u1
       valid_lft 25197sec preferred_lft 25197sec
    inet 192.168.117.100/24 brd 192.168.117.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute wlp0s16f0u1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92cc:2800:6415:b774/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Конфиг соединения аолучается такой /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Belka20.nmconnection

```
[connection]
id=Belka20
uuid=e3c4f621-XXXXXXX-0c2efd539a3f
type=wifi
interface-name=wlp0s16f0u1
permissions=
timestamp=1567866502

[wifi]
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=infrastructure
seen-bssids=50:FF:20:XX:XX:XX;
ssid=Belka20

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=XXXXXXXX

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.117.100/24
dns-search=
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, с маской тоже не работает.

Comment: пришли `ip r` и `ip a` у меня норм

Comment: Вот: http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/190910/gkyG7Vg37p.jpg

Comment: Ну а после получения адреса по DHCP, опять же, все хорошо: http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/190910/iGLpI6r56N.jpg

Comment: Я уже пробовал писать скрипт, выполняющий команду `ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.1.10 up` (а она более-менее делает то, что я хочу) перед установлением соединения - ничего не дало. Пробовал кидать это дело в автозагрузку - начинает сбоить NM, деаквтивируя соединение на eth0 и создавая новое, где уже забит нужный адрес.

Comment: У меня статика назначается сразу. Может обновить nm?

Comment: Или отключи nm добавив описание интерфейса в network/interfaces - самое простое решение для стационарных настроек

Comment: Нет, думаю, дело не в этом, у меня он последней версии, 1.6 или около того. Мне, наверное, следовало сразу обозначить, что и зачем я делаю. Вот есть у меня встраиваемая железка с Debian'ом. В железке есть встроенный хаб, куда подключаются два ethernet'овских кабеля. Один из них раздает адреса, а другой не раздает, но через него надо будет стучаться по статическому адресу. Нужно сделать так, чтобы статический адрес назначался вне зависимости от получения адреса по DHCP. К сожалению, сейчас все работает как надо только после подключения второго кабеля.

Comment: Раскидай хаб на вланы

Comment: Погуглил про vlan'ы. Отличная идея, спасибо! Должно работать. Я вот так прописал в interfaces: http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/190910/766sD48CVZ.jpg , но при этом NM метит eth0 и vlan как unmanaged. Как исправить? Отказаться от NM я не могу, т.к. он нужен для 3g, vpn и прочего.

Comment: пропиши eth-и в network/interfaces и тогда нм его трогать не будет. напишет просто устройство не управляется. остальное все работать будет